# Emgucv opens tif 16bpp greyscale file but scales intensity down to 8bpp

Tags: c#, image-processing, emgucv, tiff

I am working in an application in C# winforms, which needs to process some images which are provided as 16bpp greyscale .tif files. 
I am using emgucv to open the file and get the pixel array, but I found that actually the intensity of pixels is scaled down to 8bpp.

I used Gimp v2.10.10 to create a minimum example image that reproduces this. Using this code:

```
string a = @"White.tif";

Image<Gray, UInt16> imgSinProcesar = new Image<Gray, UInt16>(a);

this.Text = "Color: " + imgSinProcesar.GetAverage().Intensity;
```

Link to the example file: 
https://drive.google.com/open?id=14UQ4efP8lnkwA3kg6XFMxan1OF_Skvoc
The img I am using is full colored with 65535 intensity. However, the average calculated is 255, and I checked in debug that also each pixel has intensity 255.

Is this a normal behavior? I really need the 16 bits precision to do the necessary task properly.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think it is due to some auto conversion. Try loading the image in this way.

```
CvInvoke.Imread(a, Emgu.CV.CvEnum.ImreadModes.AnyDepth);
```

This will return a `Mat` object, but if you need an `Image` object you can use `.ToImage<Gray, UInt16>()`.